# Hibernate table name capitalization IFAS_util_max_object_v

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I'm trying to setup my hibernate entity to auto create the table IFAS_util_max_object_v in that exact format. No matter what I try, I can't seem to get it to capitalize IFAS. Does anybody have any ideas?

This is what I've tried.

@Table(name="\"IFAS_util_max_object_v\"")

Also, I'm using mysql db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What operating system are you using?

Mysql has a setting in the configuration file to determine if table names should be converted to lower case. As the tables correspond to files on the disk with the table name they are converted to lower case when using Windows as Windows file names are case insensitive. So it is impossible when using Windows.

You can read [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) about the details.

Comment: I'm developing the app on windows machine using mysql, but its production environment is a linux box using sybase. This new database needs to match up with an old legacy system and management has requested the table structure be identical. So what your saying is this is basically a windows issue along with sql and not hibernate?

Comment: Yes. Try to develop on a machine as close as possible to the operations machine.